# Django ORM: using extra to order models by max(datetime field, max(datetime field of related items))

Tags: mysql, django

Given the following models:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Map(BaseModel):
    ...

class MapItem(BaseModel):
    map = models.ForeignKey(Map)
    ...
```

How do I structure my ORM call to sort `Maps` by the last time either the `Map` or one of its `MapItems` was modified?

In other words, how do I generate a value for each `Map` that represents the maximum of the `Map's` own `modified_date` and the latest `modified_date` of its related `MapItems` and sort by it without resorting to raw SQL or Python?

I tried the following query but the `last_updated` values are blank when my QuerySet is evaluated and I'm not quite sure why:

```
Map.objects.extra(select={
    "last_updated": "select greatest(max(maps_mapitem.modified_date), maps_map.modified_date) 
     from maps_map join maps_mapitem on maps_map.id = maps_mapitem.id"}).
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 0:** as [Peter DeGlopper points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17845371/378638), my join was incorrect. I've fixed the join and the `last_updated` values are now all equal instead of being blank:

```
Map.objects.extra(select={
    "last_updated": "select greatest(max(maps_mapitem.modified_date), maps_map.modified_date) 
     from maps_map join maps_mapitem on maps_map.id = maps_mapitem.maps_id"}).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your join is wrong.  It should be:

```
maps_map join maps_mapitem on maps_map.id = maps_mapitem.map_id
```

As it stands you're forcing the PKs to be equal, not the map's PK to match the items' FKs.

*edit*

I suspect your subquery isn't joining against the main maps_map part of the query.  I am sure there are other ways to do this, but this should work:

```
Map.objects.extra(select={
  "last_updated": "greatest(modified_date, (select max(maps_mapitem.modified_date) from maps_mapitem where maps_mapitem.map_id = maps_map.id))"})
```

Comment: Thanks. ``last_updated`` values are now appearing but they're all the same value. I have confirmed differing values in the DB. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Adding ``select_related`` before the ``extra`` call changed the order of the results but all of the values remain the same. Looking forward to your suggestion. Meanwhile, I will update the question to reflect your first suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, `select_related` isn't actually relevant, hence my deletion.  It follows relationships in the wrong direction.