# Django-Filter query by type

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-views, django-queryset

I want to show one notification of each notification type and the most recent.
My question is how to get each notification type and show the most recent of that notification type.

```
notifications = Notification.objects.filter(**condition). \
    exclude(notification_user__in=users). \
    order_by('notificationType__priority','-start_date')[:1]
```

models.py

```
class Notification(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
description = models.TextField()
start_date = models.DateTimeField()
end_date = models.DateTimeField()
application = models.ManyToManyField('Products.Application')
notificationType = models.ForeignKey(NotificationType)
url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
region = models.ManyToManyField('Geolocations.Region', null=True, blank=True)
image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
user = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Notification_User')

class NotificationType(models.Model):
type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
priority = models.IntegerField(max_length=3)
color = RGBColorField()
```

This only shows the most recent notification independent of the notification type.
Any suggestion?

**UPDATE**

now i inserted the notifications into a list.
but in this ways doesnt work
my idea is if the notification_type the priority value (unique int) does not exist, to add into the list

```
notifications=[]    
if n.objects.filter(notification_type__priority=notifications).exists():
    notifications.append(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could capture all of the notification individually, and then merge them into one `QuerySet`:

```
c1 = Notification.objects.filter(condition=[CONDITION1_HERE]). \
    exclude(notification_user__in=users). \
    order_by('notificationType__priority','-start_date')[:1]

c2 = Notification.objects.filter(condition=[CONDITION2_HERE]). \
    exclude(notification_user__in=users). \
    order_by('notificationType__priority','-start_date')[:1]

notifications = c1 | c2  # A QuerySet that merges c1 and c2
```

This could be made smarter by using a for-loop, so that you can use `**condition` instead of having to define `[CONDITION1_HERE]` and `[CONDITION2_HERE]`, but I would need to see what the model looks like.

Comment: Nice, but there is a problem. the notification type are dynamic, it means the user can add his own notification type, if i have more than 2 that way doesnt work

Comment: That's what I thought - any way you can give a little look at the model? It would help me give a dynamic solution.

Comment: added the models, has requested

Answer (score 0):

Make the query from NotificationType and [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) the latest related notification for it. You can refer to the django docs above or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845283/django-orm-using-extra-to-order-models-by-maxdatetime-field-maxdatetime-fiel) for further inspiration.